# Very strange problem reading image width and height (Java)

Tags: java, image, swing, width, awt

I am making a method that returns the **width** and **height** of an image.
It's an ordinary 32x32 icon. Here is what I did so far:

```
    Image icon;
    String filename = "G:\\icon.jpg";

    int iconWidth = 0;
    int iconHeight = 0;

    icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filename);
    iconWidth  = icon.getWidth(null);
    iconHeight = icon.getHeight(null);
    System.out.println(iconWidth);

    JFrame window = new JFrame();

    icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filename);
    iconWidth  = icon.getWidth(null);
    iconHeight = icon.getHeight(null);
    System.out.println(iconWidth);
```

The code outputs

```
  -1
  32
```

32 is the correct width of the image. But why does it first return -1? The code is exactly the same. Removing the "JFrame" line makes it return two -1s. Could the JFrame be affecting the default toolkit?

I also tried this code:

```
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filename);
        iconWidth  = icon.getWidth(null);
        iconHeight = icon.getHeight(null);
        System.out.println(iconWidth);
```

It also returns -1. I simply can't understand why I have to call it twice to get a correct result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for `getWidth`:

> Determines the width of the image. If the width is not yet known, this method returns -1 and the specified `ImageObserver` object is notified later.

So perhaps the image is still being loaded asynchronously. Try using an ImageObserver so you can be notified when the information becomes available.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use MediaTracker or ImageObserver in this case? I could never initialize MediaTracker because I always get "The constructor MediaTracker(MainApp) is undefined". With imageObserver, I get stuck on the imageUpdate() method.

Comment: @David: What do you mean by you "get stuck" on the `imageUpdate` method? You basically need to implement `ImageObserver` to do whatever you need it to when the image information is known.

Comment: "get stuck" meaning after reading numerous examples (such as this http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt.image/ImageObserverALLBITS.htm), I still can't understand how to do it, mainly because I am not very familiar with interfaces. I also don't exactly understand what is happening. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @David: Okay, in that case I suggest you revisit interfaces before going any further with GUIs. But you just need to interface that one method to take whatever action you want when the information is known.

Comment: Sorry. I found out what was wrong, I forgot to pass the image observer to the icon.getWidth, I was still using getWidth(null). Thanks